# Foundry-workshop : sorting capabilities

Tags: sorting, ontology, foundry-workshop

I build a chart with 2 layers in Workshop, the only difference is the date bucket. As far as segmentation is the same, I would like each layer being displayed with the same color.

[image]

In the chart above, you'll see 2 series: one to display the monthly evolution of a property, the second one to display the yearly average. Each series is segmented by the same object (listed in the table above, coming from an hidden filter).  This is achieves by defining 2 layers, with exactly the same definition, except the X-axis: the date is bucked either monthly or yearly. The property is calculated on a monthly basis, so the monthly average bucket displays the input value, and the second chart dynamically calculates the yearly average.

The main issue is that the 2 blue lines are not related to the same object.
I also would like, as far as possible, to have only one legend, instead of one per layer. Currently, my workaround is to display in one case the code, in the second one the description.

Maybe I missed something, but I did not find any way to define precisely the chart colors: am I wrong?
Thus, I was wondering if there was any way to sort input data. The filter is based on the object's primary key, is is possible to sort the queryset accordingly ? Maybe the segmentation would be displayed in the same order and the colors match this order.

Or is there any other way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the title's question is quite easy: actually, the segmentation is not *exactly* the same. In the first layer, the segmentation is based on a code, the second one on the object's name. Thus, the order is slightly different.
Then solution is: use exactly the same segmentation.

I still wonder how to manage the display: view the legend for only one layer, choose lines' colors... But it looks like it's another subject and I'll probably open a new topic.